# JSlider sliding direction

Tags: java, swing

i would like to know if it is possible to know on which side of the slider the thumb is moving.  I have to implement a zoom function based on a slider and i can zoom in, but not zoom out.

```
if (!zoomSlider.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            double minY = model.getMinY();
            double maxY = model.getMaxY();

            double distanceY = maxY - minY;

            double posY = minY + distanceY / 2.0;

    if(?) {
            distanceY /= zoomSlider.getValue();
    } else {
    distanceY *= zoomSlider.getValue();
    }

            minY = posY - distanceY / 2.0;
            maxY = posY + distanceY / 2.0;

            changeMaxY(maxY);
    changeMinY(minY);
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean which side?   Why can't you zoom out, this seems unrelated?

Comment: In my calculation i need to divide some distance with the slider value, then when i move the slider to previous value i need to multiply.  At the moment i have no way to know when to divide or multiply.

Comment: I still don't understand, your comment is very confusing.  Can you post the calculation and relevant code, or better a SSCCE?

Comment: I edited my message with the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to multiply by 1, 2, 3, or 4 when i go right and divide by 1, 2, 3, or 4 when i move left.

Keep track of the "previous" slider value so you can compare it to the "current" slider value. When the value increases your multiply, when it decreases you divide.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want. A slider with the thumb in the middle, and when sliding left or right it is zooming until you release the mouse.

If so, ou should set a maximum to your slider, like 9. Then, in your loop (I guess you are in a loop, otherwise you create a mouserelease event handler), you always set the value to 5. When sliding, you take the current value and subtract 5 from it. Now the result of that subtraction should represent the speed of your zooming. 0 means, no zooming. Everything positive means zooming in and everything negative means zooming out.

Comment: Actually what i want is that when i go right i multiply and when i go left i divide.  Let's say the i have a factor of 1, 2, 3, 4 on my slider.  I want to multiply by 1, 2, 3, or 4 when i go right and divide by 1, 2, 3, or 4 when i move left.